# plone.app.testing based tests hang indefinitely and does not return control to shell

Tags: plone

After my failed test run with `bin/test` runner I get the following exception when I assume the control should return to terminal:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "bin/test", line 374, in <module>
      '--test-path', '/fast/xxx3/src/xxx-eggs/Products.xxxHospital',
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.testing-3.9.7-py2.6.egg/zope/testing/testrunner/__init__.py", line 35, in run
      failed = run_internal(defaults, args, script_parts=script_parts)
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.testing-3.9.7-py2.6.egg/zope/testing/testrunner/__init__.py", line 48, in run_internal
      runner.run()
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.testing-3.9.7-py2.6.egg/zope/testing/testrunner/runner.py", line 138, in run
      self.run_tests()
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.testing-3.9.7-py2.6.egg/zope/testing/testrunner/runner.py", line 242, in run_tests
      tear_down_unneeded(self.options, (), setup_layers, True)
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.testing-3.9.7-py2.6.egg/zope/testing/testrunner/runner.py", line 605, in tear_down_unneeded
      l.tearDown()
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.testing-4.0.2-py2.6.egg/plone/app/testing/helpers.py", line 351, in tearDown
      with z2.zopeApp() as app:
    File "/Users/moo/code/python/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/contextlib.py", line 16, in __enter__
      return self.gen.next()
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.testing-4.0.3-py2.6.egg/plone/testing/z2.py", line 242, in zopeApp
      app = addRequestContainer(Zope2.app(connection), environ=environ)
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.12-py2.6.egg/Zope2/__init__.py", line 52, in app
      return bobo_application(*args, **kw)
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.12-py2.6.egg/App/ZApplication.py", line 75, in __call__
      return connection.root()[aname]
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.6-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/ZODB/Connection.py", line 366, in root
      return RootConvenience(self.get(z64))
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.6-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/ZODB/Connection.py", line 248, in get
      p, serial = self._storage.load(oid, '')
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'load'
```

(Obvious related to ZODB internals?)

Then the execution just hangs there.

CTRL+C does nothing.

The only way to quit the test process is to CTRL+Z exit and then `kill %1`.

Any ideas? OSX.

Comment: What did you see, Mikko? http://xkcd.com/979/ ;)

Comment: I'd be interested as well ! :)

Comment: Problem is still present ... Anyone found a solution yet?

Comment: What did *you* see, @silviot?

Answer (score 4):

I've seen similar tracebacks when I fail to properly load the zcml for some
package my tests are dependent on. Have you checked your setup to ensure all the needed parts are properly loaded/installed?

Comment: Looks like it might be Selenium related. Not sure about the details yet.

Answer (score 2):

What I found is two possible reasons:

1. Problems with the loading of "dependent" ZCML as @Chris Ewing said. I use

   ```
   xmlconfig.string(
       '<configure xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope">'
       '  <include package="z3c.autoinclude" file="meta.zcml" />'
       '  <includePlugins package="plone" />'
       '  <includePluginsOverrides package="plone" />'
       '</configure>',
       context=configurationContext)
   ```

   to trigger z3c.autoload.
2. Problems with the order of testing bases. I had two bases like this:

   ```
              PLONE_FIXTURE     PLONE_FIXTURE
                  \                  / 
   LAYER =      (MY_FIXTURE1,  MY_FIXTURE2, )
   ```

   it worked with

   ```
    PLONE_FIXTURE -> MY_FIXTURE1 -> MY_FIXTURE2

    LAYER = (MY_FIXTURE2,)
   ```

-Tom